# Data validation with condition

Tags: google-sheets

I have data validation from list `B2:B` in table `Tasks`.

[image]

But I need to add some condition that selects only thous fields which belong to record with status field not equals to `Done`.

[image]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a new sheet, e.g. TasksFiltered, and put a =FILTER(Tasks!B2:C1000, B2:B1000 <> "Done") in A1
2. Put TasksFiltered!A2:A1000 as the validation range